# How to handle loading data using fetch and React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

I am new to React and somewhat new to JavaScript. I am doing a practice challenge and trying to determine how to handle `useEffect` with an asynchronous function so I can use the data later in the code.  Currently my quote variable remains `""`, but I'm trying to get it to render an actual quote from the API in the the paragraph with id of `text` along with author in the `author` paragraph. Can someone help? Disregard that I use id's repeatedly in the JSX. That is what the challenge asked for. Thanks.

The code is below but here is a link to what I have so far for the challenge within codepen.io: https://codepen.io/malbrecht13/pen/QWdNGYp?editors=0111.

```
const App = () => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = React.useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = React.useState('');
  const [quoteNum, setQuoteNum] = React.useState(0);
  
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getQuotes() {
    const data = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    const json = await data.json();
    setQuote(json.quotes[quoteNum].quote);
    setAuthor(json.quotes[quoteNum].author);
    setQuoteNum(quoteNum + 1);
  }
    getQuotes();
  }, []);
  
    return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <p id="text">{quote}</p>
      <p id="author">{author}</p>
      <a id="tweet-quote" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet Quote</a>
      <button id="new-quote" >New Quote</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Sure, but the challenge has to be done within codepen.io.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide the codepen.io link for your current approach?

Comment: I added the link.

Comment: Thanks. If you open your Developer Console with F12, you'll see the error your current code has, which is `Access to fetch at 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` You'll likely have a difficult time working around CORS restrictions while trying to fetch things remotely in codepen.io demos.

Comment: In a production application, you wouldn't have that issue because it's typical for the resources you fetch to be on the same origin your webpage was served from. If the challenge is specifically to produce a codepen.io demo which fetches from a resource like this, I think it would be reasonable to request a resource URL for the challenge which is not subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: Hmm yeah that's probably it.   The solution they have at freeCodeCamp for the challenge is here:  https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/qRZeGZ.  I took the API URL from there.  I was trying to implement my own solution using React instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fetch()` headers don't match the `$.ajax()` headers in the provided solution, so you end up getting a CORS error, preventing the response from being loaded. You had set `Content-Type` while they were setting `Accept` instead.

You should also reconsider the organization of your stateful variables, since you only need to fetch the quotes once and not each time you set the index:

```
const App = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState();
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getQuotes() {
      const response = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json', {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setQuotes(data.quotes);
    }

    getQuotes();
  }, []);

  if (!quotes) return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <p id="text">Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );

  const { quote, author } = quotes[index];
  const setNext = () => setIndex((index + 1) % quotes.length);

  return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <p id="text">{quote}</p>
      <p id="author">{author}</p>
      <a id="tweet-quote" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet Quote</a>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={setNext}>New Quote</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!